# eclipse java editor method proposal

Tags: eclipse, editor, code-completion

I recently had to work on a visual basic project. For this task I used Visual Studio 2010 and noticed I slight difference how method are proposed for code completion. If you hit CRTL+Space and start typing, all methods are suggested that contain the text. Eclipse suggests all method that start with the text.

This behavior is especially helpful if you have to work with unknown code. Can I achieve the same behavior for Eclipse? Thank you!

Comment: I believe this post belongs to stackexchange

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can download Eclipse Code Recommenders plugin - http://www.eclipse.org/recommenders/. It has a feature 'Subwords Completion' which does exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: "Java Chain Completion" Feature is nice too. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The closest you have in Eclipse is support for camel-case... This allows you to type "`new NPE`" ctrl-space and Eclipse will propose `NullPointerException` and `NoPermissionException` (depending on your current target platform).

To see which preferences you have to change the behavior of the quick assist functionality, open the Preferences Dialog and type "assist" in the search field... There are plenty of ways to tweak the behavior :-)

Comment: Camel-case is pretty cool if you know exactly what you want, it will save time.